# "Ein Fund verholen ist so gut wie gestohlen" saying definition

Tags: meaning-in-context, proverb

What is definition of this proverb or saying:

> *Ein Fund verholen ist so gut wie gestohlen.*

Is it common nowadays? Under which circumstances we use it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The version that I have found ([XVI](https://books.google.de/books?id=qs9iAAAAcAAJ&lpg=PA199&ots=6i1eYft3xn&dq=Ein%20Fund%20verhohlen%20ist%20so%20gut%20wie%20gestohlen&pg=PA199#v=onepage&q=Ein%20Fund%20verhohlen%20ist%20so%20gut%20wie%20gestohlen&f=false)) is

> Ein Fund verhohlen, ist so gut als gestohlen.

Using *wie* instead of *als* fits modern grammar, and I also have found a variant with *einen Fund*, which can be seen as more correct (Akkusativ, Maskulinum).

What this expresses is that keeping secret something which one has found is equivalent to theft.

[*Fund*](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Fund) is something that has been found.
The word *[verhohlen](https://www.dwds.de/wb/verhohlen)* is derived from [verhehlen](https://www.dwds.de/wb/verhehlen) as its past participle. The modern past participle is *verhehlt*, but it seems to be necessary to me to see *verhohlen* as a past participle here to make sense of the sentence.

The meaning of *verhehlen* is to hide, to keep secret. I think that it is not in common use today except referring to not saying something out loud, and then mostly negated: Ich will nicht verhehlen, dass ich das Wort in diesem Zusammenhang anfänglich nicht erkannt habe.

I had not heard the saying before, but I cannot say whether it is still in common use somewhere.

Answer (score 4):

> [Ein Fund verhohlen ist so gut wie gestohlen.](https://books.google.de/books?id=AmFDAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA214&lpg=PA214&dq=ein%20fund%20verhohlen%20ist%20so%20gut%20wie%20gestohlen&source=bl&ots=bW_NPWHoyp&sig=PsInw1mt3_NVVsIiIjI5nCjAqVc&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwim38mLoZzUAhVHOhQKHTYvBbMQ6AEIKzAD#v=onepage&q=ein%20fund%20verhohlen%20ist%20so%20gut%20wie%20gestohlen&f=false)

is an old German legal principle in the form of a proverb; I haven't heard it in decades. It means: Keeping a found item (e. g. a purse) for yourself is as good as stolen.

> [verhohlen](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/verhohlen) = nicht offen gezeigt, geäußert *(not shown, told)*